# Longest common subsequence of more than 1 Letter in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm, lcs

I'm trying to find the LCS of more than one letter in two strings using a `k` value. For example, if

```
k  = 3 
s1 = "AAABBBCCCDDDEEE"  
s2 = "AAACCCBBBDDDEEE"
```

then the LCS would be `4`: `"AAABBBDDDEEE"` or `"AAACCCDDDEEE"`, another example is if

```
k  = 2 
s1 = "EEDDFFAABBCC" 
s2 = "AACCDDEEBBFF"
```

then the LCS would be `2`: `"EEBB"`, `"EEFF"`, `"DDFF"`, `"DDBB"`, ... and so on. How would I be able to do it so that more than one character is in each cell of the table and if the characters are not equal I would have to use a sort, i.e. `"EF" == "FE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::is_permutation` to find if two strings contain the same characters. To store more than one character in each "cell of the table" use `std::string`.

For any questions on c++, go [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/).

**EDIT:** Here is a demo of substr's usage:

```
std::string s{"AAABBBCCCDDD"};
std::cout << s.substr(3, 3) << std::endl; // BBB

std::vector<std::string> substr_table;
substr_table.reserve(4);                     // reserve space for elements

for(std::size_t i{}; i < s.size(); i += 3){  // break up s into four substrings
    substr_table.push_back(s.substr(i, 3));
}

std::cout << "[ ";
std::copy(
    substr_table.cbegin(), 
    substr_table.cend(), 
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", ")
); // Print vector
std::cout << "]\n";
// OUTPUT: [ AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD,]
```

Comment: but would I use the std::substr(i, k) to get each substring of k length into a cell? how would I go about using it?

Comment: @trab you would use std::string::substr(i, k) to get a substr that starts at i and is k length. use std::sort to sort the string. I am not sure what you mean by "using it"

Comment: Well, I was thinking of using substr(i, k) to split up the one long string into equal parts so that I can enter each substring into the table. substring wasn't for the sorting of the letters. I also meant like a demo or some psuedocode by "using it". I appreciate the replies

Comment: @trab Let me see if I understand: You think that substr breaks the string into parts and stores that in a vector or list? No. It simply returns a string that starts at i or length k. I will add a demo of usage of substr.